# How do I pass a list of models from a table in a view to a controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm just learning about MVC and a problem I've run into is passing a list of models to a controller. I have *AutomationSettingsModel*, which contains a list of *AutomationMachines*. I've successfully populated a table in my view with checkboxes bound to data in *AutomationMachines*. However, passing the data to a method in the controller is turning out to be harder than I expected.

Here is my view with the first attempt at passing the data:

```html
@model FulfillmentDashboard.Areas.Receiving.Models.Automation_Settings.AutomationSettingsModel

<div class="container-fluid px-lg-5">

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "ReceiverSettings", "get"))
    {
        <div>
            <h2>Receiving Automation Settings</h2>
            <br>
            <table id="machineSettings" class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Automation Machine Name</th>
                    <th>Divert Line Setting    </th>
                </tr>

                @if (Model.AutomationMachines != null && Model.AutomationMachines.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in Model.AutomationMachines)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Name) </td>
                            <td> @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => item.DivertSetting) </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </table>

            <div class="row">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Save"
                onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("UpdateDivertSettings", "ReceiverSettings", new { models = @Model.AutomationMachines } )'" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

This resulted in *UpdateDivertSettings* being hit in my controller, but the data was null. After some searching, it looks like I will need to use Ajax, which I am unfamiliar with. I tried following the example at [this site](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Pass-Send-List-of-objects-from-View-to-Controller-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx), which resulted in the following addition to the view:

```js
<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save All" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("body").on("click", "#btnSave", function () {
        //Loop through the Table rows and build a JSON array.
        var machines = new Array();
        $("#machineSettings TBODY TR").each(function () {
            var row = $(this);
            var machine = {};
            machine.Name = row.find("TD").eq(0).html();
            machine.DivertSetting = row.find("TD").eq(1).html();
            machines.push(machine);
        });

        //Send the JSON array to Controller using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ReceiverSettings/UpdateDivertSettings",
            data: JSON.stringify(machines),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                alert(r + " record(s) inserted.");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

However that never seemed to hit UpdateDivertSettings in the controller. Some more searching resulting in the idea of serializing my *AutomationSettingsModel* and passing that via Ajax, but I'm not really sure how to do that. It also looks like I can do something using Ajax.BeginForm, but I can't figure out how I would structure the new form. So I'm trying to get some input on the easiest way to get this data to my controller.

Edit:
Here is the controller as it currently stands:

```
namespace FulfillmentDashboard.Areas.Receiving.Controllers
{
    [RouteArea("Receiving")]
    public class ReceiverSettingsController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly AutomationService automationService;

        public ReceiverSettingsController(AutomationService _automationService)
        {
            automationService = _automationService;
        }

        [Route("ReceiverSettings/Index")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            var refreshedView = await automationService.GetAutomationSettings( new AutomationSettingsModel(ActiveUserState.ActiveIdSite) );
            refreshedView.AutomationMachineIdSite = ActiveUserState.ActiveIdSite;
            return View("Index", refreshedView);
        }

        public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateDivertSettings(List<AutomationMachineModel> machines)
        {
            //foreach (AutomationMachineModel machine in machines)
            //{
            //    var results = await automationService.UpdateAutomationSettings(machine, ActiveUserState.IdUser);
            //}

            return Json(new { @success = true }); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give us your code in controller ?

Comment: Make sure you have mentioned the 'machines' variable in Controller's Actionmethod. This is a standard way how you can pass an object from JSON to Controller.